# python string encoding issues

Tags: python, string, unicode, encode

Is there a function in python that is equivalent to prefixing a string by 'u'?

Let's say I have a string:

```
a = 'C\xc3\xa9dric Roger'
```

and I want to convert it to:

```
b = u'C\xc3\xa9dric Roger'
```

so that I can compare it to other unicode objects. How can I do this? My first instinct was to try:

```
>>>> b = unicode(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <fragment>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

But that seems to be trying to decode the string. Is there a function for casting to unicode without doing any kind of decoding? (Is that what the 'u' prefix does or have I misunderstood?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify an encoding:

```
unicode(a, 'utf8')
```

or, using `str.decode()`:

```
a.decode('utf8')
```

but do pick the right codec for your input; you clearly have UTF-8 data here but that may not always be the case.

To understand what this does, I urge you to read:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder

Comment: Sorry if I'm being stupid here but unicode('C\xc3\xa9dric Roger','utf8') doesn't yield u'C\xc3\xa9dric Roger'...

Comment: @JohnGreenall: No, because you now have a *Unicode* value; C3 A9 is the UTF-8 encoding for the U+00E9 codepoint in the Unicode standard, a.k.a. LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE. Python will display that as `u'\xe9'` when representing the unicode string.

Comment: @JohnGreenall: Again, *please* do read the links included in my answer, there are some fundamental concepts you need to understand here.

Comment: @JohnGreenall: Byte strings are to Unicode what strings are to timestamps or numbers; representations that can differ depending on what standard you picked, but a `datetime()` object or `int()` object represents the actual value just like a `unicode()` object represents the actual text.

Comment: @JohnGreenall: "Thursday, December 19, 2013 at 7 minutes past 5 in the afternoon" is one string, and "2013-12-19 17:07" both are strings that can be parsed to the same `datetime.date()` object, for example. The same goes with byte strings and unicode values. Don't confuse the two (representation and actual value).

Comment: If you *really* want to get `u'C\xc3\xa9dric Roger'` then the encoding would be `iso-8859-1`, but as Martijn says that seems unlikely to be the right thing, unless the guy's name really is CÃ©dric (I'm glad I'm not called that).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Many thanks for the useful links. I am an experienced scientific programmer but somehow never came across character encoding issues before... Looks like I have some reading to do

Comment: @bobince Thanks for the quick fix. I suspect once I have read Martijn's literature I will rework this but for now that does what I want!

Comment: @MartijnPieters The specific problem I have is that I have a string from a json, (which I guess from json spec is unicode encoded) , that I want to compare with a string in a mongo database (UTF8 encoded). The pymongo wrapper returns the UTF8 encoded string as a unicode object. Therefore I am trying to convert the json string to utf8 but then it is a str object and can't be compared with the unicode object. Having read some of your advice it now strikes me as strange that the pymongo driver is returning UTF8 encoded stuff as unicode instead of str. No?

Comment: @JohnGreenall: Yes, if the Mongo driver is returning a Unicode value with UTF-8 bytes in it, then that is a bug in that driver, *or* someone inserted the value that way. You can *encode* to Latin 1 (which encodes the first 256 Unicode codepoints one-on-one to bytes), then *decode* from UTF-8: `mongovalue.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')`. That'll 'repair' the value.

Comment: Not to sully the good name of the pymongo folks.. Was indeed an issue of how the data was going in from one of our Php guys... Was calling encode_utf8 on a string that was already utf-8 encoded before inserting into mongo. Thanks for the help @MartijnPieters

Comment: Doh! Yes, `encode_utf8` is a poorly-named function which encourages people to do silly things like that. It should have been called `transcode_iso88591_to_utf8` (catchy!).